# Pass camera position to shader OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm trying to make a cube mapping, right now I have this code:

**vertex shader**

```
varying vec2 tex_coord;

void main()
{
 vec3 v = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);

 gl_TexCoord[0].stp = normalize(gl_Vertex.xyz);
 gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

 //gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex 
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
uniform samplerCube _tex;
void main()
{
 //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 gl_FragColor = textureCube(_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].stp);
}
```

I'd like to ask how to pass the camera position to the shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a `uniform vec3 camera_location` to the shader

Comment: Should I pass it to the shader from main program? something like this GLint cam_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "camera_location");

Comment: yes, you should - just as any uniform variable. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform

Comment: thanks, could you please tell me how to get the camera position? I've found something (look please at edit) but don't know if it is right.

Comment: First, Do you pass a GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX to your shader (If you are starting somthing new I suggest not to, since it is depracated)?